# iOS UIPageControl not show correct pages number when I using subview call parent view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I have Main`UIViewController`(named with`FlightSettingsContentViewController`), that contain a container view, the container view is the`UIPageViewController`(named with`FlightSettingContainer`);

But the layout have to set a pageControl element on the Main`UIViewController`(`FlightSettingsContentViewController`), So I drag a page control on the Main`UIViewController`.

But when the container view(subview -`FlightSettingContainer`) load, I want to set the main viewcontroller's pageControl`numberOfPages`.

I write below code on the subview-FlightSettingContainer.m to call parent viewcontroller pagecontrol page number .

```
 @interface FlightSettingContainer()
 {
     FlightSettingMainViewController *parentFlightSetngVC;
 }

 @implementation FlightSettingContainer

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];

 parentFlightSetngVC = (FlightSettingMainViewController*) self.parentViewController;

 [parentFlightSetngVC.pageControl setNumberOfPages:4];

 }
```

But the pagecontrol dots not change to 4 dots on the main viewcontroller.

have anyone know where the problem? thank you very much.

Comment: Have you checked that your parentFlightSetngVC has some object or it is nil. Use a log or use break point to check it.

Comment: Yes, parentFlightSetngVC is nil..@@ Why parentFlightSetngVC is nil? I get parenviewcontroller have fails code?parentFlightSetngVC = (FlightSettingMainViewController*) self.parentViewController; thank you

Comment: Try you code in view will appear or view did appear hope it will work.

Comment: I put the code to the view did appear, it was worked. thank you very much. please write answer , I will give you answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think as you are trying to access the `parentViewController` object in `viewDidLoad` method which will return you nil because till the `FlightSettingContainer class(Child)` view is loaded in memory it is not set as the `child` of `FlightSettingMainViewController(parent)`. So use should use your code either in `viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear` and it will work because now it set as child of its parent.

Hope it will work Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling your code too early, the relation is not set yet.

Put it in the `viewDidAppear` method